# Unable to send email using smtp python when wrapped in a function

Tags: python

Sending email using smtplib works fine however when I wrap it in a function it does not. It successfully prints "success" but i never receive the email. The same code works fine if I dont call using a function

```
import urllib.request
import smtplib
from string import Template

do = True

def report():

    sender = 'someemail'
    receivers = [someemail]

    message = Template("""From: <Land of Bugs> To: To Person <someemail>
                       MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html 
                       Subject: SMTP e-mail test <b>This is test.</b>
                       """)

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        print("success")
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print ("Error: unable to send email")


if do:
report()
```

Comment: For one thing, your `From` line and your intended `To` line are on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. While sending it via function I had tabs in my message template which messed it up. The html tags were not rendering and hence was going to my junk email. Fixing the tab issues in message template worked.

Comment: thanks, I was having that trouble when I moved my email code inside a 'tr/except' construct, and that was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

An example from [link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Send_an_email#Python)

```
import smtplib

def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,
             subject, message,
             login, password,
             smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
        header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
        header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
        header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
        header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
        message = header + message

        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(login,password)
        problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
        server.quit()
```